# What offers better performance for large datasets? Nested dictionaries or a dictionary of objects?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-datamodel

I find myself repeating this pattern when I am fetching from multiple database tables:

```
records = {'p_key': { "record": r, "A": list(), "B": list(), "C" : list() } for r in db_records}
```

I often have to group data this way because I cannot do joins across databases or there might be a situation where multiple queries is faster than multiple joins.

But performance-wise I am not sure if there is a lot of overhead to nesting dictionaries like this, and if I would be better served by creating an object with these attributes that becomes the value in the records dictionary. By performance I mean the overall cost in space and time when using a large set of nested dictionaries vs a dictionary of objects.

Comment: If you're doing joins you probably should consider using pandas.

Comment: I can't see how objects would play faster than dicts since (1) everything is basically an object, (2) almost every object has a `__dict__`

Comment: What is the purpose of `A, B, C` in the nested dict?

Comment: *every* dict is a dict of objects. A dict is an object. Everything is an object in Python. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's basically no difference in performance between dictionaries and regular class objects because internally objects are using dictionaries to handle their attributes.

However, you should consider using classes with `__slots__`.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28059785/12137863) is detailed explanation about what it is and its performance.

Another option is using pandas library to work with big dataset.